# error calling method from WCF Restfull Service - ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I'm facing a problem with a WCF Restfull Webservice, the problem is with one method the others are working correctly, then I think it isn't a general configuration problem.
I have an idea of what could be the problem but actually I don't know how to solve it.
The method have access to a third party webservice to retrieve an object of the following class:

```
[DataContract]
public class DeviceData
{
    [DataMember]
    public int DeviceDataFull { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DeviceDataVersion { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DeviceDataModel { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int DeviceDataZWave_Heal { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DeviceDataTemperature { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DeviceDataSkin { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DeviceDataSerial_Number { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DeviceDataFWD1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DeviceDataFWD1Token { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DeviceDataFWD2 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DeviceDataFWD2Token { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int DeviceDataMode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Section> DeviceDataSections { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Room> DeviceDataRooms { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Scene> DeviceDataScenes { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<DeviceItem> DeviceDataItems { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Category> DeviceDataCategories { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int DeviceDataIr { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DeviceDataIrtx { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int DeviceDataLoadTime { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int DeviceDataState { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DeviceDataComment { get; set; }

}
```

The only thing that I did in the method's code is fill this object, well in the piece of code where I'm trying to get the: `public List<DeviceItem> DeviceDataItems { get; set; }` is the problem because I test the method without it and work perfectly. this list of DeviceItem have objects of inherit classes of Device Item:

```
DeviceItemPanel : DeviceItem
DeviceItemPanelPartition : DeviceItem
DeviceItemDimmable : DeviceItem
DeviceItemThermostat : DeviceItem
etc..
```

My question: Is there any restriction in service architecture to return the class of object that I explaining above?
Because when I execute the method it remain load and after a few seconds I get the message: **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**, I don't see any other error code or anything else, I also debug the method and everything work fine the problem is when it try to return the object as a JSON format.
If any one could help me to find a solution I will appreciate it a lot.
Note this the code of the webservice method:

```
public ResultDeviceData GetDeviceData(string User, string Password, string DeviceNumber)
    {
        ResultDeviceData result = new ResultDeviceData();
        try
        {
            Identity identity = GetUserIdentityPrivate(User, Password);
            DeviceInfo info = GetDeviceInfoByNumber(User, Password, DeviceNumber);
            string url = "https://" + info.DeviceInfoServerRelay + "/relay/relay/relay/device/" + info.DeviceNumber + "/port_3480/data_request?id=lu_sdata&output_format=json";
            string jsonResult = Request_Get(url, null, null, info.DeviceInfoServerRelayToken);
            //Read Json
            var obj = JObject.Parse(jsonResult);
            DeviceData data = new DeviceData();
            data.DeviceDataFull = (int)obj.SelectToken("full");
            data.DeviceDataVersion = (string)obj.SelectToken("version");
            data.DeviceDataModel = (string)obj.SelectToken("model");
            data.DeviceDataZWave_Heal = (int)obj.SelectToken("zwave_heal");
            data.DeviceDataTemperature = (string)obj.SelectToken("temperature");
            data.DeviceDataSkin = (string)obj.SelectToken("skin");
            data.DeviceDataSerial_Number = (string)obj.SelectToken("serial_number");
            data.DeviceDataFWD1 = (string)obj.SelectToken("fwd1");
            data.DeviceDataFWD1Token = Request_Get("https://" + data.DeviceDataFWD1 + "/info/session/token", identity.IdentityFirm, identity.IdentitySignature, null);
            data.DeviceDataFWD2 = (string)obj.SelectToken("fwd2");
            data.DeviceDataFWD2Token = Request_Get("https://" + data.DeviceDataFWD2 + "/info/session/token", identity.IdentityFirm, identity.IdentitySignature, null);
            data.DeviceDataMode = (int)obj.SelectToken("mode");
            data.DeviceDataIr = (int)obj.SelectToken("ir");
            data.DeviceDataIrtx = (string)obj.SelectToken("irtx");
            data.DeviceDataLoadTime = (int)obj.SelectToken("loadtime");
            data.DeviceDataState = (int)obj.SelectToken("state");
            data.DeviceDataComment = (string)obj.SelectToken("comment");
            data.DeviceDataSections = new List<Section>();
            data.DeviceDataRooms = new List<Room>();
            data.DeviceDataScenes = new List<Scene>();
            data.DeviceDataCategories = new List<Category>();
            data.DeviceDataItems = new List<DeviceItem>();
            //Loading Sections
            var sections = JArray.Parse(obj.SelectToken("sections").ToString());
            for (int i = 0; i < sections.Count; i++)
            {
                Section section = new Section();
                section.SectionId = (int)sections[i].SelectToken("id");
                section.SectionName = (string)sections[i].SelectToken("name");
                data.DeviceDataSections.Add(section);
            }
            //Loading Rooms
            var rooms = JArray.Parse(obj.SelectToken("rooms").ToString());
            for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Count; i++)
            {
                Room room = new Room();
                room.RoomId = (int)rooms[i].SelectToken("id");
                room.RoomName = (string)rooms[i].SelectToken("name");
                room.SectionId = (int)rooms[i].SelectToken("section");
                data.DeviceDataRooms.Add(room);
            }
            //Loading Scenes
            var scenes = JArray.Parse(obj.SelectToken("scenes").ToString());
            for (int i = 0; i < scenes.Count; i++)
            {
                Scene scene = new Scene();
                scene.SceneId = (int)scenes[i].SelectToken("id");
                scene.SceneName = (string)scenes[i].SelectToken("name");
                scene.RoomId = (int)scenes[i].SelectToken("room");
                scene.SceneActive = ((int)scenes[i].SelectToken("active")) != 0;
                data.DeviceDataScenes.Add(scene);
            }
            //Loading Categories
            var categories = JArray.Parse(obj.SelectToken("categories").ToString());
            for (int i = 0; i < categories.Count; i++)
            {
                Category category = new Category();
                category.CategoryId = (int)categories[i].SelectToken("id");
                category.CategoryName = (string)categories[i].SelectToken("name");
                data.DeviceDataCategories.Add(category);
            }
            //Loading Devices
            var deviceItems = JArray.Parse(obj.SelectToken("devices").ToString());
            for (int i = 0; i < deviceItems.Count; i++)
            {
                int DeviceItemId = (int)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("id");
                string DeviceItemAltId = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("altid");
                string DeviceItemName = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("name");
                int RoomId = (int)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("room");
                int CategoryId = (int)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("category");
                int SubCategoryId = (int)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("subcategory");
                int DeviceItemParent = (int)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("parent");
                switch (CategoryId)
                {
                    case 1:
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    case 2:
                        {
                            DeviceItemDimmable dimmable = new DeviceItemDimmable();
                            dimmable.DeviceItemId = DeviceItemId;
                            dimmable.DeviceItemAltId = DeviceItemAltId;
                            dimmable.DeviceItemName = DeviceItemName;
                            dimmable.RoomId = RoomId;
                            dimmable.CategoryId = CategoryId;
                            dimmable.SubCategoryId = 0;
                            dimmable.DeviceItemParent = DeviceItemParent;
                            dimmable.DeviceItemDimmableStatus = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("status");
                            dimmable.DeviceItemDimmableLevel = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("level");
                            dimmable.DeviceItemDimmableState = (int)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("state");
                            dimmable.DeviceItemDimmableComment = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("comment");
                            data.DeviceDataItems.Add(dimmable);
                            break;
                        }
                    case 3:
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    case 4:
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    case 5:
                        {
                            switch (SubCategoryId)
                            {
                                case 1:
                                    {
                                        DeviceItemThermostat thermostat = new DeviceItemThermostat();
                                        thermostat.DeviceItemId = DeviceItemId;
                                        thermostat.DeviceItemAltId = DeviceItemAltId;
                                        thermostat.DeviceItemName = DeviceItemName;
                                        thermostat.RoomId = RoomId;
                                        thermostat.CategoryId = CategoryId;
                                        thermostat.SubCategoryId = 0;
                                        thermostat.DeviceItemParent = DeviceItemParent;
                                        thermostat.DeviceItemThermostatFanMode = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("fanmode");
                                        thermostat.DeviceItemThermostatHvacState = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("hvacstate");
                                        thermostat.DeviceItemThermostatMode = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("mode");
                                        thermostat.DeviceItemThermostatSetPoint = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("setpoint");
                                        thermostat.DeviceItemThermostatHeat = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("heat");
                                        thermostat.DeviceItemThermostatCool = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("cool");
                                        thermostat.DeviceItemThermostatStatus = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("status");
                                        thermostat.DeviceItemThermostatBatteryLevel = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("batterylevel");
                                        thermostat.DeviceItemThermostatTemperature = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("temperature");
                                        thermostat.DeviceItemThermostatState = (int)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("state");
                                        thermostat.DeviceItemThermostatComment = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("comment");
                                        data.DeviceDataItems.Add(thermostat);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                case 2:
                                    {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                case 3:
                                    {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }

                            break;
                        }
                    case 6:
                        {
                            DeviceItemCamera camera = new DeviceItemCamera();
                            camera.DeviceItemId = DeviceItemId;
                            camera.DeviceItemAltId = DeviceItemAltId;
                            camera.DeviceItemName = DeviceItemName;
                            camera.RoomId = RoomId;
                            camera.CategoryId = CategoryId;
                            camera.SubCategoryId = 0;
                            camera.DeviceItemParent = DeviceItemParent;
                            camera.DeviceItemCameraIP = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("ip");
                            camera.DeviceItemCameraURL = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("url");
                            camera.DeviceItemCameraStreamming = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("streaming");
                            camera.DeviceItemCameraVideoUrl = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("videourls");
                            camera.DeviceItemCameraCommands = ((string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("commands")).Split(',');
                            data.DeviceDataItems.Add(camera);
                            break;
                        }

                    case 22:
                        {
                            DeviceItemPanel panel = new DeviceItemPanel();
                            panel.DeviceItemId = DeviceItemId;
                            panel.DeviceItemAltId = DeviceItemAltId;
                            panel.DeviceItemName = DeviceItemName;
                            panel.RoomId = RoomId;
                            panel.CategoryId = CategoryId;
                            panel.SubCategoryId = 0;
                            panel.DeviceItemParent = DeviceItemParent;
                            data.DeviceDataItems.Add(panel);
                            break;
                        }
                    case 23:
                        {
                            DeviceItemPanelPartition panelPartition = new DeviceItemPanelPartition();
                            panelPartition.DeviceItemId = DeviceItemId;
                            panelPartition.DeviceItemAltId = DeviceItemAltId;
                            panelPartition.DeviceItemName = DeviceItemName;
                            panelPartition.RoomId = RoomId;
                            panelPartition.CategoryId = CategoryId;
                            panelPartition.SubCategoryId = 0;
                            panelPartition.DeviceItemParent = DeviceItemParent;
                            panelPartition.DeviceItemPanelPartitionAlarm = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("alarm");
                            panelPartition.DeviceItemPanelPartitionAlarmMemory = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("alarmmemory");
                            panelPartition.DeviceItemPanelPartitionArmMode = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("armmode");
                            panelPartition.DeviceItemPanelPartitionDetailedArmMode = (string)deviceItems[i].SelectToken("detailedarmmode");
                            data.DeviceDataItems.Add(panelPartition);
                            break;
                        }

                    default:
                        {

                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
            result.ResultMessage = "Data Retrieve";
            result.ResultObject = data;
            result.ResultValue = true;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result.ResultMessage = e.Message;
            result.ResultObject = null;
            result.ResultValue = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: thre might be timeout ...might be taking log time to get data from external service ...Suggestion raise faultexception so will give you proper information

Comment: Thank you very much, you know i was thinking of that but finally i don't think that this is the problem, because in debugger the method work very fast actually, and only happen after the method execute the code return.

Comment: @PranayRana I think that the problem is in the serialization that the service implicit do to convert the object into Json, what do you think? is there any configuration related with that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem returning a string in the method, and Serializing the object inside the code.

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```